# How to run ASP.NET and PHP on same machine?

Tags: php, asp.net, localhost

I already have asp.net running on PC now I have installed PHP (xampp) on my machine but it seems to be not working.

Is there any way to stop ASP.NET server (does it have a special name?) on my machine?
I have windows xp right now.

Thank you.

---

EDIT:
Thanks all of you guys. I was getting object not found error, but that was because I was putting my php files inside wwwroot folder instead of htdocs (you have to put your php files here when using xampp).

Comment: You should ask all these questions your PHP peer group (user-group) or your personal trainer.

Comment: well I have neither of those, but thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Then get together with some peers next to use. Checkout php.net for usergroups near you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this helpful: http://www.sitepoint.com/run-apache-iis-same-pc-2/

Comment: I find this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Please read this Q&A on meta: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 4):

You should install PHP for IIS instead.

Comment: Sorry I dont get that. What do u mean by using PHP for iis?

Comment: He meant to install PHP on IIS "Internet Information Services" that runs ASP.NET application in order to run PHP application. Here is a link to how to install PHP on IIS 7.0 http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php or on IIS 6.0 http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php

Answer (score 2):

Separate the web server from what is running your code for a minute.  What you have installed is not PHP, but a whole package containing Apache (the web server), PHP (runs your PHP code), and MySQL (database server).

On Windows, the common server used to serve web pages is IIS.  You can use both ASP.NET and PHP with IIS at the same time.  While there are [some hacks to get ASP.NET working under Apache](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx), I wouldn't recommend it, as it will likely cause you more headaches trying to get it working than its worth.

That means that you'll want to use IIS as your web server.  All you need to do at this point is install PHP and configure IIS to use it as a CGI application for processing `.php` files.

Instructions are here:  http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php

Answer (score 0):

It's called Internet Information Services (IIS) and you can use the IIS Manager to stop the service, or you can remove IIS entirely by going to Add or Remove Programs and then Add/Remove Windows Components.

However I find it easier to install PHP for IIS instead of using XAMPP. Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) makes it really easy (although I'm not sure if it works on older versions of IIS)

Comment: I think that's what I want, stopping the service, but how u do that?? I managed to stop "default web service" but my PHP doesn't seem to work. Whenever I try to access my PHP folder/file of wwroot I get "object not found" error MSG. any idea??